# measuring the BER for various input data rate over a custom made channel

Tags: signal, signal-processing, matlab, bit-rate

I have a wireless channel, for which I need to pass binary bits and input and measure the BER at the output.

The problem for me here is varying the data rate at the input.

How can I represent the signal data rate at the input ?
I would like to measure the data rate for say 1bps, 10bps,100bps. But I am not sure how to do that.

All I need is help in representing or making or pushing the data bits into the channel interms of bit rate.

Here is the code that I am trying:

```
N=10000; % Number of bits , size of transmitted signal x_inp=[x_1 x_2 ... x_N] 
x_inp= rand(1,N)<0.5;  % binary signal 0 or 1 % message to be transmitted                               
Tb=0.0001; % bit period (second)   


% ********************* Represent input signal as digital signal ****
x_bit=[]; 
nb=N; % bbit/bit
for n=1:1:N   % 
    if x_inp(n)==1;  % 
       x_bitt=ones(1,nb);
    else x_inp(n)==0;
        x_bitt=zeros(1,nb);
    end
     x_bit=[x_bit x_bitt];
end

t1=Tb/nb:Tb/nb:nb*N*(Tb/nb); % time of the signal 
f1 = figure(1);
set(f1,'color',[1 1 1]);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t1,x_bit,'lineWidth',2);grid on;
axis([ 0 Tb*N -0.5 1.5]);
ylabel('Tmplitude(volt)');
xlabel(' Time(sec)');
title('Input signal as digital signal');



% ********************* Define BFSK Modulation ****************************
Ac=5;  % Amplitude of carrier signal
fc1= 1.5*10^6; % carrier frequency for bit 1
fc2= 2.5*10^6; % carrier frequency for bit 0
t2=Tb/nb:Tb/nb:Tb;                 
t2L=length(t2);
x_mod=[];
for (i=1:1:N)
    if (x_inp(i)==1)
        x_mod0=Ac*cos(2*pi*fc1*t2);%modulation signal with carrier signal 1
    else
        x_mod0=Ac*cos(2*pi*fc2*t2);%modulation signal with carrier signal 2
    end
    x_mod=[x_mod x_mod0];
end
t3=Tb/nb:Tb/nb:Tb*N;
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t3,x_mod);
xlabel('Time(sec)');
ylabel('Amplitude(volt)');
title('Signal of  BASK modulation ');

% ********************* Transmitted signal x ******************************
x=x_mod;
```

Next this signal will be fed into the channel but I want to pass have a control over the data rate or the bit rate. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Tb` is meant to represent the period of a bit (i.e., 1 over the bit rate), but the rest of your code is very confused about the distinction between "bits of data" and "samples of signal".

For example, `N` seems to be the total number of bits, but you set `nb = N`, where `nb` appears to represent the number of samples per bit — this makes no sense.

The system sample rate should be an independent parameter, and the samples/bit value should be the ratio of the sample rate and the bit rate. The calculation of the modulated waveforms should only depend on the system sample rate.